# DataTable Sorting empty column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have created a data table and sorting it according to ASC order, which is working fine. I have an integer value in the column:

Here is my code.

```
     var salaryType = $.fn.dataTable.absoluteOrderNumber([
                    'TBC',
                    { value: 'N/A', position: 'bottom' }
                ]);
        jQuery('#dtTable').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
                            { "type": salaryType, "targets": 2 }
                        ],
                        "aaSorting": [[2, "asc"]],
        
        });
```

Now, Few rows are empty in column 2, and the data table is showing NaN.

Is there any way to show N/A instead of NAN with keeping integer field?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add a sample of the _source data_ you are using (not the data that ends up being displayed in the table, but a sample from your JSON, or however it is being sourced).  What does a data row with an "empty" value look like? And a data row with a non-empty value?